# GUI conflict when inheriting from QGraphicsItem+QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qgraphicsitem

I am writing a class which inherits from QGraphicsItem and QWidget. The reason I do this is because I want to make use of setPos() and setRotation() (from QGraphicsItem) to make it draggable and the customContextMenuRequested signal (from QWidget). The code looks like this:

```
class MyClass: public QWidget, public QGraphicsItem {    
  Q_OBJECT 
/* Variables and Methods here */ 
};
```

I am not an expert with QT and how it works in every detail. However from testing the code I get the feeling that MyClass actually consists of two GUI elements which may have different positions. The problem is when I put them on top of each other I either cannot get the context menu to work or I am not able to drag the thing. So I assume there can only be one of both at the top (which receives the mouse click event). MyClass is to a QGraphicsScene as a QGraphicsItem and the QGraphicsScene is set to a QGraphicsView, if this is relevant.

Is my assumption correct?

What would be an elegant way to handle this issue?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: If it helps here is what my application basically should do. 
User should be able to add multiple MyClass objects and similiar objects to the scene and move/rotate them around freely.

Answer (score 3):

`QWidget` and `QGraphicsItem` are fundamentally different things in Qt. From the docs a `QGraphicsItem` is:

> The QGraphicsItem class is the base class for all graphical items in a QGraphicsScene.
>
> It provides a light-weight foundation for writing your own custom items. This includes defining the item's geometry, collision detection, its painting implementation and item interaction through its event handlers. QGraphicsItem is part of the Graphics View Framework

Basically it is only used in a `QGraphcisScene`.

If you need a custom context menu that is available from a `QWidget` I would implement this in a custom `QGraphicsView` which inherits (ultimately) from `QWidget`. A `QGraphicsView` can be used to show a `QGraphicsScene` which will hold your custom `QGraphicsItem`.

Comment: I wanted things like the custom context menu and the tooltip to be handled by MyClass since I will have multiple MyClass objects and similiar objects within one QGraphicsScene in QGraphicsView. I would imagine it to be more complex if I handle all this within a custom QGraphicsScene class.

Comment: Then let the QGraphicScene be a QWidget that handles all the events by simply delegating them to Item children.